# The lifecycle of functions in Vue3 templates

Tags: vue.js

This may be the minimal reproduction of my problem

```html
<template>
    <span class='current-page'>
      {{ get_page_param('current') }}
    </span>
</template>
```

```js
const get_page_param = function(direction) {
  // TODO: need delete the comment
  console.log(`get_page_param(${direction}) is calling`);
  try {
    let url_string = null;
    switch (direction) {
      case 'next':
        url_string = info.value.next;
        break;
      case 'previous':
        url_string = info.value.previous;
        break;
      default:
        return route.query.page;
    }

    const url = new URL(url_string);
    return url.searchParams.get('page');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

onBeforeMount(()=>{
  console.log('before mounting');
  axios
    .get('/api/article')
    .then(response => {
      info.value = response.data;
    });
})


onMounted(() => {
  console.log('mounted');
});
```

When I run this code, I see `get_page_param(current) is calling` is printed twice in the browser's console, and both of them happen before mounting, and the second is printed after mounted

[image]

my question is

1. Why this function called twice
2. If the first call is for rendering templates, what is the reason of the second

I checked Vue's official documentation about lifecycle hooks https://cn.vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onupdated, but I still don't understand why the page will be execute the function twice during the rendering process. I think it may be front-end related knowledge, but I haven't understood it

Comment: Do you have any conditionals on the element that places your component in the DOM? Is the element in a loop?

Comment: Maybe just HMR doing its thing? Tried to build your app and see if the behavior is the same? As for why it is calling `mounted` after, `setup` is just run before the mounting process.

Comment: @StevenSpungin no, but his adjacent sibling components use conditional control

Comment: @kissu Ok, I'll learn how to build this app later and give it a try

Comment: @shellRaining What is ```route.query.page``` that you returned from ```get_page_param``` function? Also you returned **twice** in **get_page_param** function! Does it work correctly and the result shown in template is what you expect? Anyway I guess that you may have some **asynchronous** operations in your function that may affect the process. Because if you **comment** ```try-catch``` block and just return a simple text (for example), the logs are shown correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the rendering is called twice is related to the lifecycle of vue components. Vue will always render the component, when a reactive value changes. As you use a function inside a template, this will be called on each render cycle of the component.
In your example the `info.value` update will trigger a rerender. Also if using a function, vue needs to allways trigger a rerender if you change any reactive value.

That is also why you should not use functions inside the template. Whenever possible you should use computed properties and apply it inside the template. The advantage is, that vue will internally cache the value of the computed property and only update the component, if some of the values you use inside is updated.

You should make sure, you understand how the [vue lifecycle](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html) works.

A better approach would be to use a computed property that is rendered inside your template. The following shows an example that might work for you.

```js
const direction = ref('');

const pageParam = computed(() => {
  try {
    let url_string = null;
    switch (direction.value) {
      case 'next':
        url_string = info.value.next;
        break;
      case 'previous':
        url_string = info.value.previous;
        break;
      default:
        return route.query.page;
    }

    const url = new URL(url_string);
    return url.searchParams.get('page');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return '1'; // you need to return the fallback page
  }
});
```

Inside the template you use

```html
<template>
  <span class='current-page'>
    {{ pageParam }}
  </span>
</template>
```